Intersection of Record with generic key extending template literal doesn't infer result of index access
In principle (T & Record<K, U>)[K] should evaluate to U but it doesn't seem to work in the case where K is generic and extends a template literal.
function foo3<
    K extends `a${string}`,
>(k: K) {
    const a = {} as {b: 1} & Record<K, string>

    const r = a[k]
    r.toLowerCase() // Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type '({ a: 1; } & Record<K, string>)[K]'.(2339)
}

It works where K extends a "simple" type like string or a string literal.
Playground
What would be a way to make this work and remain typesafe?

Thanks jcalz, I didn't think of the reassignment, I guess I'll go with it if there is no better solution.

Ok I didn't think of that, I'll change to {b: 1} to sidestep.

Was there a reason you used a? It might be possible to sidestep that with a new type for the input.

@jcalz If you see this, don't delete your comments brother, we need to maintain the context for the next comments

@Brother58697 there was no specific reason to use a, I updated the playground link to use {b: 1}

Oh, I see it still doesn't work, I thought it would. Gotta look into it.

In cases where TypeScript fails to understand that (T & Record<K, U>)[K] is equivalent to (or a subtype of) U, I usually widen T & Record<K, U> to Record<K, U> via reassignment, since TypeScript does seem to model that the simpler Record<K, U>[K] is assignable to U.  For example:
function foo<K extends `a${string}`>(k: K) {
    const a = {} as { b: 1 } & Record<K, string>
    const _a: Record<K, string> = a; // widen a
    const r = _a[k];
    r.toLowerCase();
}

Here _a is just a but its type has been widened from {b: 1} & Record<K, string> to Record<K, string>.  Once you have that, then _a[k] can be assigned to string.
Note that TS isn't always sound and definitely isn't complete, so generic type manipulations like these can end up working or failing in cases where they shouldn't.  The widening of T & Record<K, U> to Record<K, U> is usually safe, but TS's type system has some holes that break equivalences in edge cases.   So if all else fails and you've convinced yourself that what you're doing is safe, there's nothing wrong with using a type assertion like const r = a[k] as string.
Playground link to code

But this way we lose the type of a.b because _a.b isn't defined.

a is still there, so nothing is lost.

I should have phrased it differently. Now we need to use two different objects to either access a[k] or a.b. Maybe there's something I'm missing from my understanding of OP's use case, but I feel like having just one object would be better (of course if that's not possible at all then that's a different matter)

There is just one object. a and _a are the same object. Possibly you mean just one variable, and if you find a way to make that work (without just writing a as Record<K, string> or a satisfies Record<K, string> as Record<K, string>) then you should post an answer showing that.

We can fix this if we avoid using the generic type as our index. Instead we can index it with the same type as the parameter instead and it'll be indexed correctly.
type PrefixedA = `a${string}`;

function foo<
    K extends PrefixedA,
>(k: K) {
    const a = {} as { b: 1 } & Record<PrefixedA, string>
    const r = a[k]
    r.toLowerCase() // No error
}

Playground

So here you're assigning a to {[k: \a${string}`]: string], b: 1}, which I guess works as long as adoesn't have any conflicting properties that begin with"a". You're effectively widening a` to a specific type instead of generic. Upvoted!

Thank you @jcalz. Your explanation is better than mine in the answer haha. I'll edit it to be clearer.
